# Resolve Cabal conflicts with Yesod, EclipseFP and Haskell Platform 2012.2

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod, eclipse-fp

I've tried to install Yesod / EclipseFP / Haskell Platform 2012.02 on two Ubuntu machines.

Is this possible?

(I'm new to Yesod/Haskell and can't interpret the errors, other than they look like two things require incompatible versions of other things.)

Which project is the cause of the issue?  (i.e. Who can I ask for a fix.)

```
cabal install yesod-platform
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
cereal-0.3.5.1 (new version)
crypto-api-0.10.2 (reinstall) changes: cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
crypto-conduit-0.3.2 (reinstall) changes: cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
crypto-pubkey-types-0.1.1 (reinstall)
cryptocipher-0.3.4 (reinstall) changes: cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
cprng-aes-0.2.3 (reinstall) changes: cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
cryptohash-0.7.5 (reinstall) changes: cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
hamlet-1.0.1.3 (reinstall) changes: blaze-html-0.4.3.4 -> 0.5.0.0,
blaze-markup-0.5.1.0 added
hxt-charproperties-9.1.1 (new package)
hxt-regex-xmlschema-9.0.4 (new package)
hxt-unicode-9.0.2 (new package)
hxt-9.2.2 (new package)
pem-0.1.1 (reinstall) changes: cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
certificate-1.2.3 (reinstall)
persistent-0.9.0.4 (reinstall) changes: blaze-html-0.4.3.4 -> 0.5.0.0,
blaze-markup-0.5.1.0 added
persistent-template-0.9.0.2 (reinstall)
pureMD5-2.1.0.3 (reinstall) changes: cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
pwstore-fast-2.2 (reinstall)
silently-1.1.5 (new package)
hspec-1.1.1 (new package)
skein-0.1.0.7 (reinstall) changes: cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
clientsession-0.7.5 (reinstall) changes: cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
socks-0.4.1 (reinstall) changes: cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
system-fileio-0.3.7 (new package)
filesystem-conduit-0.4.0 (new package)
tagstream-conduit-0.3.2 (new package)
html-conduit-0.0.1 (new package)
tls-0.9.5 (reinstall) changes: cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
tls-extra-0.4.6 (reinstall)
http-conduit-1.4.1.7 (new version)
authenticate-1.2.1.1 (reinstall) changes: http-conduit-1.4.1.8 -> 1.4.1.7
wai-app-static-1.2.0.3 +blaze_html_0_5 (reinstall) changes: blaze-html-0.4.3.4
-> 0.5.0.0, blaze-markup-0.5.1.0 added
wai-test-1.2.0.2 (new package)
xml2html-0.1.2.3 (new package)
yaml-0.7.0.2 (new version)
yesod-core-1.0.1.2 (reinstall) changes: blaze-html-0.4.3.4 -> 0.5.0.0,
blaze-markup-0.5.1.0 added, cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
yesod-default-1.0.1.1 (reinstall) changes: yaml-0.7.0.3 -> 0.7.0.2
yesod-json-1.0.0.1 (reinstall)
yesod-persistent-1.0.0.1 (reinstall)
yesod-form-1.0.0.4 (reinstall) changes: blaze-html-0.4.3.4 -> 0.5.0.0,
blaze-markup-0.5.1.0 added
yesod-auth-1.0.2.1 (reinstall) changes: blaze-html-0.4.3.4 -> 0.5.0.0,
blaze-markup-0.5.1.0 added, http-conduit-1.4.1.8 -> 1.4.1.7
yesod-1.0.1.6 (reinstall) changes: blaze-html-0.4.3.4 -> 0.5.0.0,
blaze-markup-0.5.1.0 added
yesod-static-1.0.0.3 (reinstall) changes: cereal-0.3.5.2 -> 0.3.5.1
yesod-test-0.2.0.6 (new package)
yesod-platform-1.0.4.2 (new package)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
http-conduit-1.4.1.8
scion-browser-0.2.8
persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
```

After using --force-reinstalls:

```
$ yesod devel
Yesod devel server. Press ENTER to quit
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring testod-0.0.0...
cabal: The following installed packages are broken because other packages they
depend on are missing. These broken packages must be rebuilt before they can
be used.
package http-conduit-1.4.1.8 is broken due to missing package
certificate-1.2.3-a05e9030a2a8a075ff79563ce724647f,
cprng-aes-0.2.3-1648d64e2ac56f39c0dcb6acde6ed388,
socks-0.4.1-cd9ac1186a4f1e3982305532e73a5f6b,
tls-0.9.5-698768ee49b4307eb7454e343d7065b9,
tls-extra-0.4.6-db5b6ed8052b04a05050ab7ec33b2fd5
package persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2 is broken due to missing package
persistent-0.9.0.4-50e8d5b2fab89513513d3d0a8c25a57c
Rebuilding application...
Forcing recompile for ./Model.hs because of config/models
Forcing recompile for ./Foundation.hs because of config/routes
Forcing recompile for ./Foundation.hs because of messages/en.msg
Forcing recompile for ./Foundation.hs because of templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet
Forcing recompile for ./Foundation.hs because of templates/default-layout.hamlet
Forcing recompile for ./Handler/Home.hs because of templates/homepage.hamlet
cabal: Run the 'configure' command first.
Build failure, pausing...
^C
$ cabal configure
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring testod-0.0.0...
cabal: The following installed packages are broken because other packages they
depend on are missing. These broken packages must be rebuilt before they can
be used.
package http-conduit-1.4.1.8 is broken due to missing package
certificate-1.2.3-a05e9030a2a8a075ff79563ce724647f,
cprng-aes-0.2.3-1648d64e2ac56f39c0dcb6acde6ed388,
socks-0.4.1-cd9ac1186a4f1e3982305532e73a5f6b,
tls-0.9.5-698768ee49b4307eb7454e343d7065b9,
tls-extra-0.4.6-db5b6ed8052b04a05050ab7ec33b2fd5
package persistent-sqlite-0.9.0.2 is broken due to missing package
persistent-0.9.0.4-50e8d5b2fab89513513d3d0a8c25a57c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting everything to build on a CLEAN install (no previous yesod platform). I've installed the Haskell Platform, BuildWrapper, Scion-browser and yesod-platform. It seems it installed http-conduit-1.4.1.7, though, so maybe 1.4.1.8 is incompatible?
Anyway, there is nothing stopping you going ahead with the install with --force-reinstalls, and then reinstall persistent-sqlite and scion-browser. Only if reinstalling these breaks yesod is an issue...

Comment: No, it just gets worse after that... (see question).  This is my fourth clean install, using two different machines.

Comment: Looks like its working now, after reinstalling persistent-sqlite and scion-browser.  Many thanks.  Is this normal behaviour for Cabal packages - i.e. is using --force-reinstall normal?

Comment: I'm afraid it's sometimes required. Yesod is made of loads of little packages and so you may get into a bit of dependency hell, so yes, reinstalling is normal, if frightening...

Comment: I prefer to never use --reinstall. It usually breaks things. I find it's conceptually simpler to just blow away ~/.ghc and start from scratch. (No need to remove ~/.cabal)

Comment: @Carl Installing EclipseFP or Yesod first both resulted in 'broken' dependencies.  Could you explain what removing .ghc does?

Comment: As far as I know, removing ~/.ghc is (roughly? exactly?) equivalent to 'ghc-pkg unregister <pkg>' for each <pkg> registered in ~/.ghc, and is a reliable way to uninstall those packages, there being no 'cabal uninstall' command.  So cabal has to install from scratch once ~/.ghc has gone.

Comment: @chrisdew have you found an installation method that still works a year later?  I used 'cabal install yesod-platform yesod-bin --force-reinstalls' b.t.w. following a suggestion by Michael Snoyman.  But my eclipseFP is somewhat broken and I believe that installing yesod first hasn't helped.